# Can I pass additional parameters through shopify oAuth2

Tags: oauth, shopify

So I'm going through the oAuth2 process for Shopify and I am doing the following.

> SHOP_NAME.myshopify.com/admin/oauth/authorize?client_id=xxxxx&scope_string=xxx&redirect_uri='mysite.com/shopify_callback'

Then exchanging the temporary token for an access_token by doing

> SHOP_NAME.myshopify.com/admin/oauth/access_token?client_id=xxxxx&client_secret=XXXXX&code=xxxx

I am then getting back the access_token which I store - all good.  However the initial launch point to get the App could be one of several places and I'd like to pass an additional parameter along with the oAuth2 parameters ..something like

> SHOP_NAME.myshopify.com/admin/oauth/authorize?client_id=xxxxx&scope_string=xxx&redirect_uri='mysite.com/shopify_callback'&myparam='uniqueid'
>
> SHOP_NAME.myshopify.com/admin/oauth/access_token?client_id=xxxxx&client_secret=XXXXX&code=xxxx&myparam='uniqueid'

so that the return is `access_token` AND `myparam`.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach required parameter in `redirect_uri`

> SHOP_NAME.myshopify.com/admin/oauth/authorize?client_id=xxxxx&scope_string=xxx&redirect_uri='mysite.com/shopify_callback?myparam=uniqueid'